# How can I do <p> tag word wrapping?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Consider:

[image: Screenshot]

As shown in the above image, the exceeding words need to hide and dotted line needs to show. How can I do this word wrapping in CSS and AngularJS?

Comment: using `text-overflow: ellipsis` or else you could use custom filter which will trim the value

Comment: You cannot limt to apply that only to words. It will place ellipsis wherever necessaary to shorten, even in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *text-overflow* style available in CSS:

```css
text-overflow: clip|ellipsis|string|initial|inherit;
```

Use *ellipsis* to trim the word and show dots.

See *[Word wrapping in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)*.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a class for the clipping and apply it with 'ng':

```css
.is-clipped {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: What is "ng"? Some command-line thingamajiggy for Angular?

Answer (score 0):

**Filter**

```javascript
app.filter('ellipsis', function() {
  return function(text, length) {
    if (text && text.length > length) { // If it is not null then check length
      return text.substr(0, length) + "........";
    }
    return text;
  }
});
```

Use this filter in the view as:

```html
<span ng-bind="post.post_content | ellipsis:200"></span>
```

To do it in CSS, you can use the ellipsis property. Please visit *[CSS text-overflow Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)* (W3Schools).

Comment: you mean ng-bind is enough?

Comment: Yes `ng-bind` is enough..as you content is not having nay `html` tags

Comment: your filter gonna throw an error when value is `null`

Comment: null means it will retun null only. I dont think this will throw error. If so, I Have edited the code. please comment nw

Comment: `text.length` will evaluated as `null.length` which will throw error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` try this code on you end with null value

Comment: sorry pankajparkar. But it works properly. I checked it

Comment: Thanks. Thats great  pankajparkar

Answer (score 0):

To make the text cut off with ellipses when it overflows the container, with CSS you need to apply several properties to your container (in this case `<p>`):

1. **`text-overflow: ellipsis;`**

   This is what defines the actual display (the ellipsis, or the dotted lines the way you called them).

   Here is the list of all possible display types: *`text-overflow: clip|ellipsis|string|initial|inherit;`*
2. **`overflow: hidden;`**

   This tells the content to cut-off when it overflows. If you don't set this, the text will simply display in full, without cut-off.

   Other options are: `overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;`
3. **`width:`**

   You need to set the vertical limit of the container, i.e. the point when the content needs to cut-off. Since you are using ellipses, you need to factor this into the width.

   ***Important**: For the content to cut-off, the container needs to be a block or inline-block element (e.g. no `display: inline`) and `width` needs to be applied in `px`, not in `%`.*
4. **`white-space: nowrap;`**

   This tells content that it should not wrap when it reaches the container limit set in step 3. If you don't set this, the content will simply wrap to the next line, and none of the text-overflow will apply.

   All possible white-space values are: *`white-space: normal|nowrap|pre|pre-line|pre-wrap|initial|inherit;`*

   ***Note:** This will cut the text off at the point where the container ends, which will sometimes result in not so nice language syntax issues (e.g., words cut off mid-way, or a space between the last word and the ellipses).*